# How to check if the resource id belongs to raw folder or drawable folder in android studio

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I'm making an application that has a lot of videos and images and I'm using them randomly in the same activity,
so how can I check if the "resource id" I'm using from the database is a video or image so I can deal with each one separately?

Comment: can you not just create different arrays for these so that you at least know from which array you're taking ?

Comment: Use different arrays, or make a class that tells which type is currently there and put all in the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the type in the db as well, as its own field.  Then you're good.

I really wouldn't suggest using resource ids in the db though.  Resource ids aren't stable-  the same resource may have different ids in different builds.  This means when you update your app, all those ids may be broken.  If you need to reference resources in an external file like a db, I'd suggest using the name and doing a name lookup-  that will work unless you rename the file.